# iPhone, how to calculate iPhone device three axis angle via UIAcceleration?

Tags: iphone

as topic,

I am try to use the code as follows :

`xAngle = 90.0 *x;
    yAngle =  90.0* y;
    zAngle =  90.0* z;`

but seem it is not right (x,y,z is the UIAcceleration attributes x, y and z)

am I miss some thing in this algorithm ?

thanks for your help

Best .

Answer (score 1):

```
cos (angleXaxis) = x / sqrt(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)

cos (angleYaxis) = y / sqrt(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)

cos (angleZaxis) = z / sqrt(x^2 + y^2 + z^2)
```